# NodeJs + Mysql Multi Query with chain method

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

Hi friends I have to ask the mysql query repeatedly in my application with Node js. I will shape the second interrogation according to the result of the first interrogation. The following code example does not work. Can you help me? You can support the functioning of the queries do not hang.

```
 let sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS miktar FROM orders";
  connection.query(sql, function(err, result) {
    if (err) throw err;
    let sqlAnother =
  "SELECT COUNT(*) AS miktar FROM orders WHERE result=" +
  result[0].miktar +
  "";
connection.query(sqlAnother, function(err, result) {
  if (err) throw err;

  callback(result);
});
 });
  connection.end();
```

Comment: What is it that's not working with your code?

Comment: 2. query dont give me any result. and have not any err

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in one call with a subquery:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS miktar FROM orders WHERE result = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM orders)
```

If this returns a result in the MySQL CLI, then your code must provide this result to `callback`. Otherwise it's just that no row in `orders` happens to have a field `result` that contains the exact amount of rows in the table.